# How can I move this class to separate file in python?

Tags: python, oop, import

Please have a look at the following code:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        # list to keep track of instances of Sub()
        self.sub_list = [] 
        # create instances of Sub()    
        self.a = Sub()
        self.b = Sub()
        # append instances to sub_list    
        self.sub_list.append(self.a)
        self.sub_list.append(self.b)


class Sub:
    # function to remove the instance from sub_list
    def remove_self(self):
        x.sub_list.remove(self)


x = Main()

# remove instances of Sub() from sub_list
x.a.remove_self()
x.b.remove_self()
```

My goal is to have objects with a **method to delete themselves** from a list in a different class, where they are created.

The above code works for this, but I don't like that I have to call the method by using `x` directly.

**The main issue** I'd like so solve, however, is that I can't figure out how **to move the class `Sub` to a separate file**, as I can't access `sub_list` anymore.

Is there a better way to do this?

*Side note: I'm working on a project with PyQt, where `Main` is my MainWindow and `Sub` represents some UI elements that can be dynamically created and also closed. I'd like to keep all functionality within these elements if possible.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to not have a `sub_list` at all. It seems unnecessary since instances of `Sub` each get a field to themselves in your example. That being said, if you want to move `Sub` to a different file you can do it like so:

`sub.py`:

```
class Sub:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def remove_self(self):
        self.parent.sub_list.remove(self)
```

And then in your `main.py`:

```
from sub import Sub
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sub_list = []  
        self.a = Sub(self)
        self.b = Sub(self)  
        self.sub_list.append(self.a)
        self.sub_list.append(self.b)
```

Then you can do:

```
x = Main()
x.a.remove_self()
```

or

```
x.sub_list[0].remove_self()
```

Or alternatively, and this is the approach I recommend, get rid of `remove_self` and add a new function to `Main` that takes care of removing `Sub` instances:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sub_list = []  
        self.a = Sub(self)
        self.b = Sub(self)  
        self.sub_list.append(self.a)
        self.sub_list.append(self.b)

    def removeSub(self, index):
        self.sub_list.pop(index)

x = Main()
x.removeSub(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If this can be done without `sub_list`, I'd be happy do to so. In my project I need to keep track of all instances and be able to call a `submit` method on all of them at a later point. Can this be done without some sort of data structure to keep track?

Comment: @michaelh In that case what you currently have is good. Either of my two proposed methods should work for you. Be sure to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you, and best of luck.

Comment: I just tried your solution with my code and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Separation of concerns works by having you split code on the bases of function, as in OOP. Whatever model you'd like to have in a different file is called into your main program using "from filename_without.py> import class_name" as is in your models file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).